# golang include url redirect?

Tags: git, go, module, goland

We are having a situation that would have us tearing our hair out, except that there is one bright light at the end of tunnel ... if we could figure out how it was accomplished.

Part of the problem is GO being integrated with git, and go.mod referencing specific versions (tags) of a module stored in the repo.

Our project is called "bam".  In the go.mod it is referencing:

```
require (
   git.footprint.net/vyvx/harvester/vbusmeta.git v6.0.1+incompatible
)
```

The "+incompatible" seems to be some sort of notation that GO is adding, and is not part of the tag in the repo, which is "v6.0.1".  We do not think that this "+incompatible" is part of our problem.

Ok, so now GO is instructed to go to the repo on git.footprint.net, and download the module vbusmeta, using the tag v6.0.1.  So far, so good.

One of the source files in this module has this:

```
import (
    "l3git/vbusmeta/api/equip"
)
```

l3git was a local machine hosting repositories back in the stone age of the development of this project.  all of those repos are now hosted at git.footprint.net/vyvx/harvester (which is another internal repository -- you won't find it by entering that url in your browser).

So when trying to compile this module, it kicks out a complaint about not being able to find "l3git" as a repository.

But since GO downloads the specific version of v6.0.1 of that module, WE can't change "l3git" to something else.  It is not part of our project source (bam), it's part of the downloaded module vbusmeta v6.0.1.

All of this would have us running in circles except that for ONE of the developers, who put all of this project on her machine a while ago ... it works.  Using the GOLAND development environment, when she drills down into the downloaded modules, and looks at the source in "vbusmeta v6.0.1+incompatible" (so it is clearly the same one) ... the text in that include says "git.footprint.net/vyvx/harvester/vbusmeta/api/equip".  ALSO, when we look into the actual module source downloaded to her GOPATH directory, that file still clearly says "l3git/vbusmeta/api/equip".

I do not know if there is something in the GOLAND development environment that enables this repo translation, or if there is something you can set in GO env that can do this, but *somehow* something is translating the bad "l3git" repository reference to the good reference on git.footprint.net/vyvx/harvester.  But if we don't know what's doing that on her machine, we can not replicate it for the other developers working on the project.

(We do not know if it is a feature in GOLAND directly, or if the GO env is set up slightly differently inside GOLAND and outside.  So it still may be a GO feature.  Or even a git feature, as opposed to a GOLAND feature that is causing this to happen.)

Does anybody have any idea how to handle repository url surgery in GO and/or GOLAND ?

Oh ... this is *not* being accomplished by an "insteadOf" clause in .gitconfig.  She doesn't have that in her .gitconfig, and when we tried it in another developer's .gitconfig it did not work anyway.

Comment: Either: Move the repo l3git/vbusmeta/api/equip to somewhere reachable, update (new version or fork) git.footprint.net/vyvx/harvester/vbusmeta.git to use the new location and use the new vbusmeta in your code (sane version). Or: Use a `replace` directive in your go.mod switching the crapy l3git/vbusmeta/api/equip to something reachable (either again a reachable git repo, or a local copy). The only _sane_ in the long term is to use proper packages and reachable repos: You must fix the upstream packages!